# spring-boot mvc tests: how to disable validation?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

i have controllers with `@Valid` annotation. by default, mockMvc tests triggers that validation. i would like to disable this for some tests because it requires much more work to prepare valid input, while only partial input is enough for most tests

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a standalone setup, you can provide a mock `Validator` instance through `setValidator` method:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setValidator(mockValidator);
```

If not, you would have to provide a mock `Validator` bean via a test `@Configuration` and mark the bean as `@Primary`. Preferably, you would have a different profile for those kinds of tests so as not to disable validation for other ones.